# How do I made ngrok server run forever?

Tags: ngrok

I want to have my website online on ngrok 24/7, but it's session will expire after 2 hours. Is there any way to have it run forever, or any alternative software that I should use?

Answer (score 2):

If you sign up for an account on ngrok.com, whether free or paid, you will have tunnels that run with no time limit (aka "forever").

Comment: No its limited for 2 hours in free versions

Comment: It is only limited to 2 hours for anonymous sessions, but if you sign up on the website and use an ngrok authtoken associated with that account, you will have no time limit.  You can sign up for a free account.

Comment: You are right! Do you know can we open multiple tunnels as well?

Comment: Under the free plan you can run 4 tunnels per ngrok process (see https://ngrok.com/pricing).

Comment: @user2738058 Do you have a reference to ngrok being unlimited for authtoken accounts?  All I can find is it saying "longer session times" still seems finite

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about domain address persistence and you use Discord and you want to use it just for testing, sharing it for friends to view you can use this:
https://github.com/winter-b/ngrok-bot
It's a Discord bot which executes shell commands every two hours to restart ngrok tunnel, get the url, and send it to the specified Discord channel.
First create a Discord bot, how to here https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro, get the bot token, put the bot in your Discord server, get the channel id you want to send url's to, put the discord bot token and channel id in settings.json

run in directory

```
npm install  
npm start
```

it's not perfect, but gets the job done for particular scenarios

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you must first prepare the paid version of ngrok, then define a robot using below Python code to remake your URL again on ngrok within a period of  12 hours for example. Note that using the paid version of ngrok, Your URL will not be changed and it just needs to be re-marked once every 12 to 24 hours:

FIRST INSTALL "pyngrok" on your python {pep install pyngrok}

#hears the python cod:
import time
from pyngrok import ngrok

## Set the Ngrok auth token

ngrok.set_auth_token('YOUR OTHE TOKEN')  #REPLACE WITH YOUR OTHE TOKEN GIVEN FROM NGROK SITE

while True:
# Start an HTTP tunnel and bind it to port 8080 with a subdomain
http_tunnel = ngrok.connect(8080, proto='http', subdomain='YOURSUBDOMAIN')

```
# Get the public URL for the HTTPS tunnel
public_url = http_tunnel.public_url
if http_tunnel is not None:
    # Get the public URL for the HTTP tunnel
    public_url = http_tunnel.public_url

    # Print the public URL
    print(f'Public URL: {public_url}')

    # Keep the HTTP tunnel open for 12 hours
    time.sleep(12*60*60)

    # Kill all Ngrok processes to close the tunnel
    ngrok.kill()
else:
    # If the tunnel was not created, print an error message and try again
    print('Failed to create Ngrok tunnel. Retrying...')
```